# jquery fullpage.js not working properly while navigating on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery fullpage.js for single scroll.  I have the menu section linking to different html files.  While clicking on the menu, flickering occurs due to the html page load.  How do I control flickering on my screen when using fullpage.js?

Comment: We can't help resolve the issue if you don't show us what you have done so far

Comment: what have u tired ?

Comment: Do you have a test site to show?